# Websockets issue while subscribing multiple shares it over writes previous

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

The problem is to find a simple way to subscribe multiple channels using a single websocket in python

#2nd instrument overrides 1st instruments how to get data for both instruments and store

```
from time import sleep
from alice_blue import *
import mylib # contains user credentials
import pdb

username = mylib.username
password = mylib.password
api_secret = mylib.api_secret
twoFA = mylib.twoFA

file = open(r"C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\scripts\tradebook.txt", "r")
access_token = file.read()

def main():
    global socket_opened
    global alice
    global username
    global password
    global twoFA
    global api_secret

    alice = AliceBlue(username=username, password=password, access_token=access_token, master_contracts_to_download=['NSE', 'MCX', 'NFO'])
    socket_opened = False

    def event_handler_quote_update(message):
        global data
        data = message

    def open_callback():
        global socket_opened
        socket_opened = True

    alice.start_websocket(subscribe_callback=event_handler_quote_update,
                          socket_open_callback=open_callback,
                          run_in_background=True)

    while (socket_opened == False):
        pass
        alice.subscribe([alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', 'TATASTEEL'), alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', 'ACC')],LiveFeedType.MARKET_DATA)
        sleep(2)

    while True:
        print(data)
        sleep(2)
  pdb.set_trace()


  sleep(2)
```

am new to python help me with code.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the specific part of the code that has the issue, and what you have tried to do to prevent it. It is very difficult to just look at a ton of code an tell you what to do to fix it.

Comment: in function 
def event_handler_quote_update(message):
        global data
        data = message

i will receive live socket data of subscribed instrument using websockets, when i try to subscribe multiple instruments its over rides previous instrument